# Integral of Cosecant of double angle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was finding the solution to the differential equation 
$$
\sec(y) \frac{dy}{dx}=2\cos(x)\sin(y).
$$
I ended up with the equation 
$$
\csc(2y)dy=\cos(x)dx
$$

I integrated w.r.t. the corresponding differentials, 
I got $$-1/2\ln(\csc 2y + \cot 2y) = \sin(x) + c$$
But on wolfram,
$$
 \int \csc (2y) dy = \frac12\ln\cot(y) 
$$
While 
$$
\int \sec(2y) dy = \frac12 \ln(\sec 2y + \tan 2y)
$$
I wanted to ask how are these two integrals different?
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: *Mathematica*:  $y(x)\to \cot ^{-1}\left(e^{-c_1-2 \sin (x)}\right)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\csc2y+\cot2y=\frac{1+\cos2y}{\sin2y}=\frac{2\cos^2y}{2\sin y\cos y}=\cot y$$

The anti-derivative of $\csc2y$ is $-\dfrac12\ln|\csc2y+\cot2y|+k=-\dfrac12\ln|\cot y|+k$.

Comment: I got the same answer but how is that equal to -(1/2)ln(coty)?

Comment: @H.Ahmed Please check the edited answer